# HDX RealTime Engine can't connect with ICACLIENT - EndeavourOS

Tags: linux, archlinux, citrix, arch

I have a problem on my EndeavourOS installation.

I have installed the following packages:

```
~]$ yay -Si icaclient
Repository                    : aur
Name                          : icaclient
Version                       : 23.9.0.24-1
Beschreibung                  : Citrix Workspace App (a.k.a. ICAClient, Citrix Receiver)
URL                           : https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html
Lizenzen                      : custom:Citrix
Gruppen                       : Keine
Bietet                        : Keine
Ist abhängig von              : alsa-lib  curl  gst-plugins-base-libs  gtk2  libc++  libc++abi  libidn11  libjpeg6-turbo  libpng12  libsecret  libsoup  libvorbis  libxaw  libxp  openssl  speex  webkit2gtk
Optionale Abhängigkeiten      : xerces-c  webkit2gtk  libc++
Abhängigkeiten herstellen     : Keine
Prüfe Abhängigkeiten          : Keine
Ist in Konflikt mit           : bin32-citrix-client  citrix-client
Replaces                      : Keine
AUR-URL                       : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icaclient
Erstmals eingereicht          : Thu 08 Dec 2011 07:49:34 PM CET
Stichworte                    : Keine
Zuletzt geändert              : Thu 28 Sep 2023 06:54:46 PM CEST
Betreuer                      : buzo
Beliebtheit                   : 0.534514
Stimmen                       : 171
Veraltet                      : No

~]$ yay -Si hdx-realtime-media-engine
Repository                    : aur
Name                          : hdx-realtime-media-engine
Version                       : 2.9.700-1
Beschreibung                  : Plug-In for Citrix Receiver to support clear, crisp high-definition audio-video calls, particularly with Microsoft Skype® for Business.
URL                           : https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/additional-client-software/hdx-realtime-media-engine-29700.html
Lizenzen                      : custom
Gruppen                       : Keine
Bietet                        : Keine
Ist abhängig von              : icaclient  libxv  libpulse  pulseaudio  libsndfile
Optionale Abhängigkeiten      : Keine
Abhängigkeiten herstellen     : binutils  tar  xz  awk
Prüfe Abhängigkeiten          : Keine
Ist in Konflikt mit           : Keine
Replaces                      : Keine
AUR-URL                       : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hdx-realtime-media-engine
Erstmals eingereicht          : Fri 22 Apr 2016 11:27:18 AM CEST
Stichworte                    : Keine
Zuletzt geändert              : Fri 08 Sep 2023 10:16:17 AM CEST
Betreuer                      : dimitry_de
Beliebtheit                   : 0.208222
Stimmen                       : 15
Veraltet                      : No
```

When I connect to the citrix service everything is okay, but the HDX RealTime Connector is trying to connect and crashes:

```
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: couldn't read configuration from a file /var/lib/RTMediaEngineSRV/settings.conf
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st plasmashell[3061]: free(): invalid next size (fast)
    Nov 27 13:58:40 h0st systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 112462/UID 0).
    Nov 27 13:58:41 h0st systemd-coredump[112463]: [] Process 112435 (RTMediaEngineSR) of user 1000 dumped core.
                                                    
                                                    Stack trace of thread 112448:
                                                    #0  0x00007fc380ed583c n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8e83c)
                                                    #1  0x00007fc380e85668 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3e668)
                                                    #2  0x00007fc380e6d4b8 abort (libc.so.6 + 0x264b8)
                                                    #3  0x00007fc380e6e390 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x27390)
                                                    #4  0x00007fc380edf7b7 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x987b7)
                                                    #5  0x00007fc380ee1ad4 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x9aad4)
                                                    #6  0x00007fc380ee4353 free (libc.so.6 + 0x9d353)
                                                    #7  0x00000000012e1c07 hid_get_indexed_string (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xee1c07)
                                                    #8  0x00000000012d755b _ZNK32AvLyncHumanInterfaceDeviceFinder16EnumerateDevicesERSt6vectorISt10shared_ptrI8AvDeviceESaIS3_EE (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xed755b)
                                                    #9  0x0000000000eadad7 _ZN8endpoint13MediaControls28EnumerateDevicesAsyncCommand2DoEv (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xaadad7)
                                                    #10 0x00000000012f9815 n/a (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xef9815)
                                                    #11 0x00000000013507c7 _ZN3vos4base6Thread14ThreadFunctionEPv (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xf507c7)
                                                    #12 0x00007fc380ed39eb n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c9eb)
                                                    #13 0x00007fc380f577cc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1107cc)
                                                    
                                                    Stack trace of thread 112439:
                                                    #0  0x0000000001e98ec9 interp_planes_px0y2_px2y2_ssse3_ar (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0x1a98ec9)
                                                    ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
    Nov 27 13:58:41 h0st systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@39-112462-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
        Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: couldn't read configuration file /var/lib/RTMediaEngineSRV/settings.conf trying to create one...
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: couldn't read configuration from a file /var/lib/RTMediaEngineSRV/settings.conf
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: ioctl (HIDIOCGSTRING): Invalid argument
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st plasmashell[3061]: free(): invalid next size (fast)
    Nov 27 13:58:46 h0st systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 112502/UID 0).
    Nov 27 13:58:47 h0st systemd-coredump[112503]: [] Process 112476 (RTMediaEngineSR) of user 1000 dumped core.
                                                    
                                                    Stack trace of thread 112488:
                                                    #0  0x00007ffb0ceaa83c n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8e83c)
                                                    #1  0x00007ffb0ce5a668 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3e668)
                                                    #2  0x00007ffb0ce424b8 abort (libc.so.6 + 0x264b8)
                                                    #3  0x00007ffb0ce43390 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x27390)
                                                    #4  0x00007ffb0ceb47b7 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x987b7)
                                                    #5  0x00007ffb0ceb6ad4 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x9aad4)
                                                    #6  0x00007ffb0ceb9353 free (libc.so.6 + 0x9d353)
                                                    #7  0x00000000012e1c07 hid_get_indexed_string (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xee1c07)
                                                    #8  0x00000000012d755b _ZNK32AvLyncHumanInterfaceDeviceFinder16EnumerateDevicesERSt6vectorISt10shared_ptrI8AvDeviceESaIS3_EE (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xed755b)
                                                    #9  0x0000000000eadad7 _ZN8endpoint13MediaControls28EnumerateDevicesAsyncCommand2DoEv (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xaadad7)
                                                    #10 0x00000000012f9815 n/a (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xef9815)
                                                    #11 0x00000000013507c7 _ZN3vos4base6Thread14ThreadFunctionEPv (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0xf507c7)
                                                    #12 0x00007ffb0cea89eb n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c9eb)
                                                    #13 0x00007ffb0cf2c7cc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1107cc)
                                                    
                                                    Stack trace of thread 112480:
                                                    #0  0x0000000001e98f36 interp_planes_px0y2_px2y2_ssse3_ar (RTMediaEngineSRV + 0x1a98f36)
                                                    ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
    Nov 27 13:58:47 h0st systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@40-112502-0.service: Deactivated successfully
```

Currently I have no clue, why this is happening. The permissions seems to be fine and the config file exists...

I also tried different versions of the icaclient and hdx-realtime-engine from the AUR and deactivating ipv6 as mentioned in another post.

Thanks for help!

Kind regards

Ulli